# How to loop background music?

Tags: android, media-player

I'm using background music in my application but i'm notice that after i upgrade my android version to lollipop 5.0 the background music not start from the first beat and the music stop for a 500 mill and then repeat. I'm sure the problem is because the lollipop. any idea how to fix it?

```
public boolean playBackgroundMusic(int id){     
    loopMusic = MediaPlayer.create(context, id);
    try {
        loopMusic.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    loopMusic.setLooping(true);
    loopMusic.start();
    return loopMusic.isPlaying();
}
```

Comment: **"i upgrade my android version to lollipop 5.0"** : What do you mean by this? Do you mean you have upgraded your device to Lollipop or you have changed the min or target version of your app to be Lollipop?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely due to a change in the buffering mechanism of `MediaPlayer`. `MediaPlayer` is a streaming player that doesn't necessarily keep the whole audio in memory and might need to buffer the stream in the background before it plays.

If you want responsive looping you should consider using a [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

From the docs:

> This allows applications [...] without having to suffer the CPU load
>   and latency of decompressing during playback.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try with **setNextMediaPlayer(mp)**? Don't use **setLooping()**.
You will need to make a method while the `MediaPlayer` is over to set the next `MediaPlayer` over and over again.

This solved the loop problem for me. Hope it helps.